# .Net Core migration path from 2.1 using .Net 4.5 libraries

Tags: .net, .net-core

We have a running .Net Core 2.1 API. 
For legacy reasons we share a set of business logic layer assemblies currently in .Net 4.5 because they are used by our Windows WinForms .Net 4.5 application as well.

I would like to upgrade the API to .Net Core 3.1, but as that requires netstandard21, which .Net 4.5 won't be, I would like some feedback on my options - if I understand correctly.

As I see it we are stuck for now.

If I upgrade the legacy assemblies to netstandard21 - I can't use them from the .Net 4.5 WinForms app

If I keep the legacy assemblies on .Net 4.5, I can't use them in the .Net Core 3.1 - because they are not netstandard21

.Net Core 3.1 supports WinForms - so will it be a feasible way to go for porting the old WinForms app to .Net Core 3.1 - if all third party libs can be found in .Net Core 3.1 compatible versions.

The final option is to wait for .Net 5, maybe slowly start working on a migration with the previews, but I assume that requires our third party libraries to support .Net 5 as well.

Has anyone been in the same offset - having a .Net Core Api mixed with .Net 4.5 libraries - and how are you planning to move forward?

We have 10 year+ legacy code - so re-implementing is not an option.

Best regards 
/Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a shared project and add your shared business logic there and then create two projects, one for WinForms and one for ASP.NET which have reference to the shared project.

You can read more about shared project here: [Shared Projects code sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows)

Comment: We already have two solutions (one for Api and one for WinForms) - including multiple projects each. 
8 of the projects are referenced by both solutions.

Comment: My question is more - what framework target should these 8 projects have to be able to be used in both .Net Core 3.1 and .Net 4.5 runtimes

Comment: Well as you said yourself there are no framework target to support both. So I would change those 8 project to shared project so it can be maintain in one place. And also create 8 mirror project with .net core and 8 with .net 4.5

Comment: We are talking multiple 100k+ lines of code - maybe crossed 1 mio LOC. Not a valid option to try to maintain duplicate code across large team on such a large code base

Comment: The code is not duplicated. All your codes stays in its original place. You just need to change the project type to shared project. And there are not a single line of code in the mirror projects, just a reference to the shared project

Comment: Ok, sorry for me misunderstanding - I'll give it a second read then and get back

Comment: I see the point of shared projects but still think the refactoring will be to big. The 8 projects are being referenced by each other - and the biggest of the projects has 70+ references to other assemblies. And as I read it, shared assemblies are not able to have references - they need to be the lowest layer. But in general I think the concept could solve the challenge. Will try on some of the smaller projects and see how it works. Maybe the references can be not in the shared part - but in the referencing projects. Then we just need to update two projects if adding new refs to the solution

Comment: i'll mark yours as a correct answer as I can see a way to the goal using Shared Projects. I will try to use .Net Preview as well, as this might be a better fit on the long term for us - and then we just wait to the end of the year with upgrading from .Net Core 2.1. With shared projects I still see a risk of the 2x8 mirror projects drifting apart and a reference be updated in one but not the other platform.